# How do we loop through a list of strings and extract a substring from each string, given a string as a start and a string as an end?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings which are extracted from the HTML of a site. How do I splice each of these strings, so it only returns the substrings that are between "name"> and </h4. I tried an example outside of the for loop, using the .find() method and it worked. I am just not sure how to get this to work inside the for loop. Below is my code:

```
for tag in tags:
    start = tag.find('"name">')+len('"name">')
    end = tag.find('</h4')
    lst.append(tag[start:end])
```

(Where tags is my list of strings I am iterating through.)

Comment: But you are using a loop?

Comment: Why are you using extracting substrings like this? If you're scraping a web site you should use Beautiful Soup to parse it.

Comment: I am already using Beautiful Soup. When I scrape through the website and return the content of a tag I get this (1st element of the list of tag results): <h4 class="fireitem-module--title--1XSqg" itemprop="name">KNP Complex</h4>
I do not know how to only print the "KNP Complex" portion. I've been stuck on this for several days, thats why I wanted to try using the substring method instead, since I am able to return the tag, but not the substring I want.

Comment: What does `lst` even end up being?

Comment: @Soum if ```tag.get_text()``` or ```tag.string```. See the docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/